# Printing word document with fields in C# with adding field values at run time

Tags: dynamic, field, addition, doc

I need to print a word document. but every time i print the document i need to add some values at certain positions and then print the document. I think there is option available of adding fields in doc file and giving it the value at run time.
I have googled it but haven't find appropriate solution. 
Is there any such option available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using variables and changing their values is the solution for this issue.
we can change vales of a variable at run time in c# using following code:

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("replace1").Value = "This is a test"
```